# Get amount of Bitcoins at an address with PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I'm using [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com), but they don't have an API call to get the amount of Bitcoins per address, but only per account, which is a collection of addresses.

Does anyone have an API call for this? I'd prefer to not to reinvent the wheel by setting up my own Bitcoin server/daemon as suggested in this other SO thread:

[How to check Bitcoin address balance from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481478/how-to-check-bitcoin-address-balance-from-my-application#answer-20517619)

Answer (score 8):

Hmm, would this work for you:

```
<?php
function getBalance($address) {
    return file_get_contents('https://blockchain.info/q/addressbalance/'. $address);
}

echo 'Address Balance: ' . getBalance('1EzwoHtiXB4iFwedPr49iywjZn2nnekhoj');
```

Using the https://blockchain.info/q API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the balance of a Coinbase address, you may not get the expected results because Coinbase shuffles your bitcoin around to different addresses internally. The only way to get the true balance is by account.

```
<?php
$accountId = '<Account Id>';
$account = $client->getAccount($accountId);
$balance = $account->getBalance();
$btc = $balance->getAmount();
```